# Поможем моему ProgressDialog найти его отступы

Tags: android, progress-bar

Есть у меня приложение, в приложении есть ProgressDialog горизонтального типу, вот его код:

```
final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
pd.setTitle(R.string.creating_a_gif);
pd.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.preprocessing));
pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
float duration = (float) (mModel.getGifEndPosition() - mModel.getGifStartPosition());
int totalFrames = (int) ((duration / SECOND_IN_MILLIS) * mModel.getFps());
pd.setMax(totalFrames);
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pd.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
    ctx.getString(android.R.string.cancel),
    (dialogInterface, i) -> FFmpeg.getInstance(ctx).killRunningProcesses());
pd.show();

mBuilder.setProgressListener((f, ft) -> {
  pd.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.frames_processed));
  pd.setIndeterminate(false);
  new Thread(() -> {
    pd.setProgress(f);
    pd.setSecondaryProgress(f);
  }).start();
});
mBuilder.setCompleteListener(pathToGif -> {
  pd.dismiss();
  goToPreview(pathToGif);
});
```

Если выполнить этот код в первый раз в течение работы приложения, то мы можем увидеть, что UI диалога не имеет отступов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если выполнить код еще раз (причем даже если мы зайдем на текущий экран заново), то все отступы будут на месте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я должен сделать, чтобы диалог принимал нормальный, с отступами вид с первого раза? Проявлялось на Android 5.0 и 5.1.1

Comment: А если создавать обычный AlertDialog, то такой проблемы не возникает? Понятно что не решение, просто это может помочь определить в чем проблема. И если на обычном AlertDialog повторяется, то можно попробовать AlertDialog из support library.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте присвоить диалогу какую нибудь тему при создании.

Например:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
}else{
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: увы не помогло(